# How To Know The Certain Area Of The Polygon in Google Maps

Tags: laravel, google-maps, laravel-5.6

I have apps (I'm using `laravel 5.6` with `google maps v3`) zone layer and property layer :
[image]

the property layer is the black polygon, and the zone layer is the coloring polygon (W1, W2). The problem is how can i know the zone of the property. From the picture the zone of the property will returning the W1 zone dan W2 zone.

I have three tables (`property [id, no_property]`, `zone[id, name]` and `geometry[lat, lon, geometriable_id, geometriable_type]`) the relation between `property` - `geometry` and `zone` - `geometry` i use polymorphic relation.

I've no idea where to start to solving this problem. Could anyone here help me to find the solution for my problem.

Thank You

Comment: What is zone layer? What is zone in this case?

Comment: @Tpojka zone layer in this case is a layer used to explain the usefulness of the area. so when I have a polygon layer property that is placed above the zone layer, it will automatically tell me that the property area is in a certain zone. is that possible to do?

Comment: I mean is it some maps api feature or you created that zone? If that is API feature, can you post link to docs?